# How To remove articles 'the', 'a', and 'an' from the beginning of the string dataframe's column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove the articles "the", "a" or "an" from the beginning of the strings in the dataframe column with python (pandas).
All the options I tried removed these from any places in the string, but I want just to remove them at the beginning. Not all the strings in the column include the same articles and even some of the columns data do not have these articles. I used different ways like replace, remove the part of string and also tried to see if I can go with removing specific number of characters at the beginning.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you give a minimal reproducible example, please ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex sub and the pandas apply function. The caret `^` means that matching is only at the start of the line, so later matches aren't found by mistake.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': ['the fat cat', 'a fat cat on the mat', 'an elephant']})
df['Col'] = df['Col'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('^the |a |an ', '', x))
```

To apply the substitution to the whole DataFrame use the the `applymap` function.  An example would be to change the last line above to

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub('^the |a |an ', '', x))
```

And finally, if you want to match `The` or `An` then just change the regex expression to;

```
'^[Tt]he |[Aa] |[Aa]n '
```

Output

```
    Col
0   fat cat
1   fat cat on the mat
2   elephant
```

Comment: Good to hear, can I kindly ask you to accept my answer